# Pidgin Crash Notification?

Tags: ubuntu, crash, pidgin

My Pidgin seem to be crashing a lot. 
Unfortunately I notice it only an hour after. 
How do I make it to do some sort of notification/restart? 
Whenever it crashes? I'm Using Ubuntu 10.04 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I misunderstood. If that is what you are looking for then you might be interested in [Apport](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport).

---

You will probably want to look in the following location `~/.purple/logs`

OR

Read: http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/TipsForBugReports
           http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/GetABacktrace

OR

Read: [DebuggingProgramCrash](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash)

Comment: that's not what I'm searching for. I wish to be notified when the program crashes, like with a window or something, so I know it's down, nothing more.